# Why do I get an Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse error

Tags: javascript, ejs

When I run the following ejs code using `npm start`, it displays syntax error.

Here is the code. I think in my guess, the error is related to the arrow(=>).

```
<% JSON.parse(documents).forEach(document => { %>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="<%= document.Key %>" data-bs-toggle="tab"
      href="#list-<%= document.Key %>" role="tab" aria-controls="list-<%= document.Key %>" style="min-width: 200px;"><%= document.Key %></a>
<% }) %>
```

Here is the exact error displayed when I run localhost:3000/ on the browser

```
SyntaxError: /javascript/views/pages/dashboard.ejs:14
    12|     <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    13| 
 >> 14|     <% JSON.parse(documents).forEach(document => { %>
    15|         <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="<%= document.Key %>" data-bs-toggle="tab"
    16|           href="#list-<%= document.Key %>" role="tab" aria-controls="list-<%= document.Key %>" style="min-width: 200px;"><%= document.Key %></a>
    17|     <% }) %>

Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Why do you assume that it is due to the arrow function? The error message says `Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) `  which tells you that what you pass to `JSON.parse` is not valid JSON.

Comment: message means that `documents` is not valid JSON

Comment: thank you for your response.but,how can i check whether documents is valid JSON or not?

Comment: `how can i check whether documents is valid JSON or not?` you already know that it is not valid because `JSON.parse` complains about it not being valid. Without knowing what the content of `documents` is it is impossible to tell you why exactly you get that error message. Currently, we can only say that the content of `documents` is not valid JSON. There are linters you can use localy,  or an online linter like [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `JSON.parse(documents).forEach(document..`  into `documents.forEach(document`

Comment: All we know about `documents` is that it isn't JSON. There's nothing in the question to say it is an array.